# pg-promise ; I cannot save the result set, the only data returned I got is a Promise object

Tags: typescript, pg-promise

As a premise, I am totally new to pg-promise, javascript and typescript, so is quite possible that my question is trivial.

I am playing with pg-promise as I will need to fetch some data from postgresql, and I need to use typescript.

I am running the "any" method with a predefined query, encapsulated in a wrapping function. From any(..) I got returned only the Promise object, which I do not know how to use (or even if I should use it). I can print the result set in console, so I am sure that it connects to the db.

Please be gentle, is my first post in stackOverflow

I tried some examples on the pg-promise page, but probably my issue is so trivial that is not enlisted in the site, or perhaps is so simple that is not considered worth explaining :-)

````
function simpleSelect(db: any, query:string){
    var ret :any[] = []
    return db.any(query, [] )
    .then( (data:any) => {  
        return data
    }).finally(db.$pool.end)
    ```

This is the Promise object i got returned
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
````

Comment: Hello Rob T.  This is a great start to a question!  Could you please add links to the examples and why they didn't help you?  That will quickly narrow down the question to facilitate a good answer.

Comment: You are probably displaying the result returned by `simpleSelect` directly, as opposed to the data it resolves. You should first learn how to use promises in JavaScript.

Comment: Hi @vitaly-t, I recognise  that the problem is on how I manage the Promise. Is perhaps a synchronicity problem? I can see the result set fetched from the db AFTER the main execution ends,  and I cannot understand why the function does not wait the promise to result before returning. ```10:23:14 GMT+0000 (GMT) - Connecting to host 10.0.3.201, db ats_whitelabel
10:23:14 GMT+0000 (GMT) - Returned from function:  Promise { <pending> }
10:23:15 GMT+0000 (GMT) - Read data into 'then' [ { id: '1', modified: 2019-11-05T11:17:36.085Z } ]

```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
function simpleSelect(db: any, query:string){
    var ret :any[] = []
    db.any(query, [] )
    .then( (data:any) => {  
        return data
    }).finally(db.$pool.end)
```

return data once promise is resolved instead of returning promise